# Storing Facebook user info best practice?

Tags: database, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, storage

So I have been looking at creating a REST API for a program and we are allowing some users to login in with Facebook.
When a user signs up to my program via Facebook, I need to produce a user profile with basic personal information (eg. firstname, lastname etc.) and then also specific program information (eg. career choices).

The specific program information will obviously be entered manually by the user, **but the personal information can possibly come directly from Facebook**.

I was thinking that we can show a "sign up form" that has the necessary program specific fields and then personal fields ALREADY prefilled with their Facebook personal info (they can change this info if necessary).

My question is:
**When a user creates an account on my program, should I be storing their personal information from Facebook into my database, or constantly retrieve their personal information from Facebook everytime I need to display their personal info?**

If I store it in my database, I am just worried that there will be outdated information in the long term (eg. user changes personal info on Facebook but not reflected on our system). Should my program always synchronize to the user's FB account?

Our main goal is to provide another login method into our program. Having personal details of the client will not affect the program's functionality at all (only used for users to see details of other users).

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely go for storing that personal information from Facebook in your database.

Having a look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension), you can see the recommended workflow is to obtain a long-lived access token after the initial registration short-lived one. As for personal information being out of sync, once that long-lived token expire (~60 days), you'll need to refresh it (customer needs to login again), at which point you can use the short-lived token to also update your database records.